# What is an effortless way of toggling the Single Application Mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, shortcut, spotlight

I normally toggle the Single Application Mode via the terminal or in the app TinkerTool. However, I wish I could toggle it with just one click and without going through the menus of TinkerTool, for example via an icon in the top panel. Is there a sweet way of doing it?

By the way, I just migrated to MacOS.

Comment: Do you mean TinkerTool?

Comment: create a short shell script with contains  _defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true_ and use e.g. [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to create a clickable wrapper. To disable the mode use _false_ istead of _true_ . Thinking of it, if you execute the shell command via AppleScript you can use e.g. Siri to change in and out aingle app mode.